# What different between IData<out T> and IData<T>

Tags: c#

What different between **IData< out T>** and **IData< T>** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

consider,

```
class Fruit {}

class Banana : Fruit {}

interface ICovariantData<out T> {}

interface IData<T> {}
```

and the functions,

```
void Peel(IData<Fruit> fruitData) { }

void Peel(ICovariantData<Fruit> fruitData) { }
```

The function that accepts `ICovariantData<Fruit>` will be able to accept `ICovariantData<Fruit>` or `ICovariantData<Bananna>` because it is a covariant interface and `Banana` is a type of `Fruit`,

the function that accepts `IData<Fruit>` will only be able to accept `IData<Fruit>`.

Comment: +1 for the simplest way of explanation